# Are interfaces allowed in UML sequence diagrams

Tags: uml

Is it valid to have an Interface as part of a sequence diagram.  For instance, is the following UML valid? The purpose of the interfaces is to show extensibility and testability points in the design.  You could extend by providing a different implementation for each interface and better test by replacing the interfaces with mocks.  However, I don't know if this violates the rules of UML. Thanks in advance.

```
GameService:IGameService     GameRepository:IGameRepository
           |                            |
           |                            | 
           |--------------------------->|
           |                            |
           |                            |
           |                            |
```

P.S.: Sorry for the poor's man diagram.

Comment: You can not reverse engineer the code of a Java interface. Please note that the flow of the method can go through an interface when you trace it. It means that an interface can be not be first on the left in your sequence diagram but could be anywhere after.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my part is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course a lifeline in a sequence diagram can represent an (instance of an) interface. From the perspective of the diagram, it doesn't matter much---there are no restrictions on where the operations/messages on the events should come from.
If you want to indicate that the operations have to come e.g. from the signature of the target (`IGameRepository`), you have to document/encode this separately, e.g. in OCL.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. Both classes and interfaces are subclasses of Classifier in the UML metamodel. Classifiers are the ones linked to the elements in the sequence diagram